# Can't get IntelliJ IDEA to connect to MS SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, intellij-idea

I'm trying to connect to MS SQL Server through IntelliJ IDEA.

After creating a new login in SSMS, confirming that it works fine and enabling all IPs in `TCP/IP` settings. (I added the 1433 port as well), I am getting an error when I try to connect to localhost:1433.

I'll attach a screenshot here, hoping that someone has an idea of what can I do.

[Image with error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o52z8.png)

Comment: Does the same happen if you use jtds driver?

Comment: Do run IDE under 9 JDK or have 9 JDK configured as your project JDK? Please make sure you are running IDE under 1.8 JDK, see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879 about how to configure IDE boot JDK.

Comment: @moscas haven’t tried, I’ll do that when I get to my PC and I’ll come back with an edit..

Comment: @Andrey, pretty sure I am running JDK 9 both on my project and my IDE in general

Comment: The JDK IDE runs under is displayed in Help | About dialog. If you have 1.9 there this is the most probable cause of the failure. Configure IDE to run under 1.8 JDK instead, see mentioned link on how to configure.

Comment: @Andrey, it is set on 1.8, but seems to work fine on jtds drivers, as moscas mentioned, so I’ll consider this solved. Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. The Microsoft drivers seem not to work, so I used JTDS instead. Thank you!

Comment: You should mark your answer as solution. I just wasted lot of time and then found your post and it is correct: with jTds it works instantly.